# android-W/PackageManager: Package named<> does not exist

Tags: android, android-package-managers

I published an android app and after a while, when I wanted to edit it and publish a new version. So I imported it in Android Studio.

My problem is the Android Studio does not run my app on my device and shows this message:

[image]

What can I do to fix it?

Comment: Check u import is successful. Try to sycn the gradle again and run the project .

Comment: If build was successful, that means your java syntax is correct. But you probably had other instllation of your app on device. Try go Settings->Applications->Select your app->Top-Right menu-> Uninstall for all users. Then reinstall it from Android Studio.

Comment: Another way: from Android Studio open Gradle tab (at top-right corner). In drop-down list select project->project(root) -> install-> uninstallAll. Then run app again

Comment: @DanilOnyanov same message plus this : E/Pm: Failure details: Bundle[{android.content.pm.extra.STATUS=1, android.content.pm.extra.PACKAGE_NAME=***, android.content.pm.extra.LEGACY_STATUS=-1, android.content.pm.extra.STATUS_MESSAGE=DELETE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR}]

Answer (score 2):

according to this [link](https://github.com/Yalantis/uCrop/issues/84) I add these attributes on my app's build.gradle and the problem is gone :)

```
// Gradle Plugin 2.0+  
 android {  
   defaultConfig {  
     vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true  
    }
```

}
or

/

```
/ Gradle Plugin 1.5  
 android {  
   defaultConfig {  
     generatedDensities = []  
  }  

  // This is handled for you by the 2.0+ Gradle Plugin  
  aaptOptions {  
    additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"  
  }  
 }
```